# Uncaught TypeError: const is null

Tags: javascript

first of all i am very new to js

my code:

```
const test = document.getElementById("div1")
test.addEventListener("click", e => {
    console.log(e)
})
```

It should return this really long text with things you can to with the event, but It only returns an error:

Uncaught TypeError: test is null

but it is defind. So i dont see what I messed up

Comment: Let's see the HTML please

Comment: make sure you're testing for it after the HTML has loaded

Comment: It's null because it did not find an element in the page with id "div1".

Comment: div1 exists in my html